# Find out if XIB exists at runtime

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, xib, nsbundle

Is there anyway to do it?

I've tried `pathForResource:ofType:` on NSBundle and it can't find the xib when it's really there. If I try to load it and it doesn't exist `loadNibNamed:owner:options:` crashes and so does `nibWithNibName:bundle:`

Basically, I want to know at runtime whether I should register a xib or just a class for a given cell type on a collection view.

Comment: "I've tried pathForResource:ofType: on NSBundle", what do you mean it doesn't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure `pathForResource:ofType:` is not working? It's not just the common xib / nib confusion?

(.xib-files are `ofType:@"nib"`)...

```
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *path = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"crapXib" ofType:@"nib"]; // file is called crapXib.xib
if (path){
    // whatever...
} else{
    // whatever else
}
```

Comment: It works. 
List all the files in the main bundle, you will see the *.xib changes to *.nib

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `NSFileManager` to check if file exists, if application is not localized  all `.nibs` live in root directory of `.ipa`, for example:

```
NSString * root = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [root stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MainViewController.nib"]])
{
    // exisits
}
```

Comment: @Daij-Djan, thank for you comment, are you think is better to use `pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:forLocalization:` ?

Comment: no `pathForResource:ofType:` automatically checks languages. you would need multiple calls to `pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:forLocalization:` to make up for it